# templateService.Parse not able to parese Tuple used in view(MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

I am trying to parse a .cshtml with **tuple** and tuple used for acces two models in the view same time,  but it is not working throwing error, but if I am using only one model than same this is wotking.

Here is my code:

**Controller:**

```
var deviceModel = new DevicesInformationDataViewModel { };
            var eventModel = new EventsInformationDataViewModel{ };
            var templateFolderPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Views\\EmailTemplates");
            var emailTemplatePath = Path.Combine(templateFolderPath, "EmailTemplates.cshtml");
            var templateService = new TemplateService();
            var emailHtmlBody = "";
            string email = data[1];
            ViewBag.info = data[0];
            if (data[0] == "DeviceInfo")
            {
                deviceModel.Address = data[2];
                deviceModel.Description = data[3];
                deviceModel.eDescription = data[4];
                deviceModel.Fault = data[5];
                deviceModel.Type = data[6];
                deviceModel.TypeCode = Int32.Parse(data[7]);
                deviceModel.DriftCompensation = Int32.Parse(data[8]);
                deviceModel.AlarmSensitivity = data[9];
                deviceModel.Status = data[10];
                emailHtmlBody = templateService.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(emailTemplatePath), deviceModel, ViewBag.info, null);
            }
```

**View:**

If using like this, not working:

```
@model Tuple<DevicesInformationDataViewModel,EventsInformationDataViewModel>
```

but if using like this, it is working:

```
@model DevicesInformationDataViewModel
```

Can any body tell me what I am doing wrong and please tell me how can I resolve 
this issue?

Comment: what is your action model return type, it should be tuple type

Comment: You have specified the 2nd parameter of `.Parse()` as `deviceModel` which is type of `DevicesInformationD‌​ataViewMode`l, not `Tuple<DevicesInform‌​ationDataViewModel,Ev‌​entsInformationDataVi‌​ewModel>`.

Comment: ok, so  can I pass two model in view without using Tuple.

Comment: No, but in any case you should be using one view model that contains all the data you want in the view

Comment: Yes that true, but for me template will be common for sending email only the data will change and that data I am getting from different model and that model data I have to pass in the view